# Mock asserting into callbacks

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm having the following problem when unit testing (working code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ZTF5ZoAV9sY)]

Assuming we have this:

```
var (
    userDomain UserInterface
    Tx         TxInterface
)

type UserInterface interface {
    Get() (*User, error)
}

type TxInterface interface {
    Exec(fn func() error) error
}

type User struct {
    ID int64
}

func (u *User) Get() (*User, error) {
    return &User{
        ID: 1,
    }, nil
}

type WithTx struct{}

func (t *WithTx) Exec(fn func() error) error {
    /* more logic here */
    return fn()
}
```

Assuming we have the following 2 services:

```
func GetByID() (*User, error) {
    user, err := userDomain.Get()
    return user, err

}

func GetByIDWithTx() (*User, error) {
    u := &User{}
    /** Notice this implementation **/
    if err := Tx.Exec(func() error {
        user, _ := userDomain.Get()
        u = user
        return nil

    }); err != nil {
        log.Print("Tx err", err)
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

They are the same but once goes directly to the Get method, the other one runs into a callback fn. So far so go, both works like a charm. Again code is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ZTF5ZoAV9sY)

I'm trying to mock the userDomain and Tx for unit tests, so my mocks look like this:

```
var (
    getUserFromMock func() (*User, error)
    getFromMock     func() error
)

type userMock struct{}

func (u *userMock) Get() (*User, error) {
    return getUserFromMock()
}

type txMock struct{}

func (t *txMock) Exec(fn func() error) error {
    return getFromMock()
}
```

When testing `GetByID` I have no problem whatsoever.

```
func TestGetByID(t *testing.T) {
    userDomain = &userMock{}
    Tx = &txMock{}

    getUserFromMock = func() (*User, error) {
        return &User{ID: 3}, nil
    }

    user, err := GetByID()

    if user.ID != 3 {
        t.Fatalf("error")
    }

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("error")
    }
}
```

However, When I try to testing `GetByIDWithTx`, I cannot assert the mock values:

```
func TestGetByIDWithTx(t *testing.T) {
    userDomain = &userMock{}
    Tx = &txMock{}

    getUserFromMock = func() (*User, error) {
        return &User{ID: 4}, nil
    }
    /**** Mocking callback response ****/
    getFromMock = func() error {
        return nil
    }

    user, err := GetByIDWithTx()

    if user.ID != 4 {
        t.Fatalf("error") /** It fails here **/
    }

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("error")
    }
}
```

I assume, at the moment I'm trying to assert the callback is still running in another routine but I'm just speculating, I don't have any idea what is going on here. I rather not use any library for a spy, I just want to understand how to solve this. Thoughts?

[Go PlayGround HERE](https://play.golang.org/p/ZTF5ZoAV9sY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never calling the `fn` given to the `txmock`. Change `txMock.Exec` to:

```golang
type txMock struct{}

func (t *txMock) Exec(fn func() error) error {
    return fn()
    // return getFromMock()
}
```

and remove `getFromMock()` function completely. It will then call `getUserFromMock` function to get the mocked user.

Comment: woaw, I guess I'm so burned out rn, thank you for the help!

Comment: Sometimes it just needs an extra pair of eyes.